# Menu does not slide out correctly

Tags: css, html

I've included a  tag pointing to the jQuery website, but my separate, inline  tag doesn't do ANYTHING in the browser. Not even an error message. I'm almost certain I have no syntax errors and my filepath is correct, but I have no idea what else could be causing the problem.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#menu-wrapper').click(function(){
        $('#slide-menu').animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 250);

        $('body').animate({
            left: '15%'
        }, 250);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Those are the script tags. The whole page is available at http://budbranchblossom.com

**edit**
The jquery works fine but there is a problem with the css styling.

Comment: Your javascript works fine. You have a CSS problem though. Add in the css definition of the slide-menu some top and z-index to start with.

Comment: Once a question has answers you can't really change it because the answers won't then make sense. If you have follow-up questions, ask them separately.

Comment: Sadly I can't ask them because the site won't let me.

Comment: Plus I left my original question up, it's just that I added another one. Please don't edit that again, I need this question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as expected. The reason why you dont see anything happen in your page is because `body` is not in a `position` applicable for take into account the `left` property you are animating, also, you should add `z-index` properties in order to be able to see them properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally forgot about that!

Answer (score 1):

1. Animating the whole body is not good, because you move everything, also your slide-menu, this means for what you want you need to animate your slide-menu negativ 15% because the whole body is left 15%.
2. Use transform translate because of performance
3. Animating with % is ok on small site, on big sites this is a performance issue. Instead use the 400ms (time before user thinks nothing happens) to get px of the way you want to animate.

**For your issue:**
Nothing happens because you body needs to be absolute (not good actually) and your site-menu is missing top:0px; it also should have a z-index

if you add:

```
alert("start")
```

to your click function, you see that the click actually works.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not too worried about performance, as the purpose of the site is merely a small company's contact information and I don't expect traffic. If setting the body element's position to "absolute" is not recommended, how else should I circumvent the problem?